# Поток информации или что нужно знать о JAVA?

Tags: java, jsp

Как правильно расставить приоритеты, в какую сторону плыть? Наверное каждый программист, который только начитает изучать JAVA на уровне WEB разработки, задавался подобными вопросами.
    Я начинающий JAVA программист, который пытается перешагнуть с SE в EE технологии. Но в большом потоке информации иногда тяжело определится, что нужно именно Вам? Для каких целей применяются те или иные технологии? Поэтому я составил список вопросов, которые должны заинтересовать не только меня, но и всех начинающих разработчиков (извините, если на первый взгляд вопросы окажутся для кого-то примитивными). Со временем список будет расширяться. 
    Буду весьма благодарен Вашим ответам, желательно с примерами кода, на подобие: System.out.println(“Это хороший пример”), а вот это …*…*…*... – плохой пример, он будет работать, но через ..опу!

**Вопросы:**

1. Какая разница между jsp и jspx. Когда и какую структуру применять? Как они связаны с html, xhtml, и xml? На сколько подобные подходы устарели или это используется везде?
2. Что такое jsf и как оно связано с jsp (jspx), и можно ли (нужно ли) применять то и другое одновременно?
3. Servlet – это основа и без них никуда? Или есть другие подходы?
4. Когда что применяют: Spring, Hibernate, Struts … (много других)? Насколько они упрощают жизнь и увеличивают скорость разработки?
5. Разница между JavaBeans и EJB. Есть ли у Вас пример кода, что такое JB, а что такое EJB?
6. Как правильно создавать архитектуру приложения, чтобы не запутаться в бесконечном коде? Какие инструменты Вы лично для этого используете (UML – или это не катит)?

Спасибо за Ваши ответы, буду очень благодарен за Ваши ссылки на некоторые небольшие WEB проекты простенькие для понимания (может Github или что-то другое).

Comment: Мне, когда я столкнулся с подобными вопросами помог [этот сайт](http://www.java-course.ru/students/students.php).

Comment: Я как раз на этом сайте (неделю назад)  и начал понимать более общую картину. Действительно очень хорош, но мне кажется есть момент на которых нужно было б остановиться более подробно. Но и за то спасибо автору.

Comment: Еще есть неплохий вводный материал [тут](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-124877.html), если, конечно, осилите прочитать весь тред. Много готовых ответов, можно найти на [JavaTalks](http://javatalks.ru). Там, кстати, форумчане пишут на вышеупомянутых вещах форум/блог/cms: можно и исходники поизучать и вопросы позадавать непосредственно авторам.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ответы (упрощенно):**

1. JSP и JSPX практически одно и то же. JSPX это XML совместимая версия JSP
2. JSF это стандартный Sun/Oracle фреймворк реализующий паттерн MVC, где JSP используется в качестве компонента View
3. Servlet это основа - без них реально никуда - это must have в багаже Java Web developer'а
4. Все зависит от целей разработки+предпочтений тим лидеров. Судя по всему вы начинающий девелопер, посему не забивайте себе голову. Старшие товарищи (работодатели или тим лидеры) тебе сами скажут работаем в таком то фреймворке - твое дело взять под козырек и выполнять.
5. JavaBeans - это грубо говоря Java объект имеющий стандартизованный интерфейс для работы с ним через т.н. геттеры и сеттеры. EJB - забудь это почти вымершая технология, если его и спрашивают то только для понтов. JB == JavaBeans
6. Займись в первую очередь паттернами. UML в топку.

Начинайте изучать в таком порядке:

1. JavaBeans
2. Java Reflection
3. Servlet
4. JSP/JSPX
5. Паттерны (в первую очередь MVC)
6. Struts
7. Hibernate
8. JSF
9. Spring
10. EJB (факультативно)

**P.S.** Не пишите никогда JAVA, а пишите просто Java - неверное именование языка наводит на размышления об уровне квалификации

Comment: я бы UML не списывал, выучить хотя бы значение стрелочек и прямоугольников - лишним не будет. А паттерны и без знания их названий в GOF можно применять если есть опыт.

Comment: Спасибо Barmaley за указанный путь по которому нужно идти.  И у меня сразу возникли ещё вопросы относительно jsp. Jsp относиться к back-end или front-end разработки? Как я понимаю back-end – всё то, что происходит на стороне сервера? Jsp при запуске создает сервлеты (back-end) , которые отрабатывают на стороне сервера. А если jsp смешать с другими технологиями (и можно ли так делать) такими как JavaScript или Jquery, то это как бы уже разработка пользовательского интерфейса и наверное относится к front-end разработке, или я не совсем правильно понимаю (тот же самый GWT)?

Comment: @Crocusid не зацикливайтесь на терминах, какая разница back-end или front-end? По назначению JSP это front-end, а по реализации back-end :)

Answer (score 3):

Все начинающие кодеры пытаются найти "универсальную формулу знаний", типа придут на форум, зададут вопрос, прочитают 5-10 книг, которые им посоветовали, и станут профессионалами. 
На самом деле позже придет понимание, что не все книги подходят для тебя, возможно некоторые вещи лучше понимать в картинках, а не сразу из доков на оф.сайтах. Что не на практике возможно тебе и не придется использовать веб, а может и придется по работе, потому что сам, дома, развернуть корпоративный портал не так уж просто и интересно, что в книгах обычно частные случаи, а на практике без костылей не обойтись, что пока выучишь одну технологию досконально, она морально устареет и еще много всего.

Comment: > Все начинающие кодеры пытаются найти "универсальную формулу знаний"

Вы никогда не были начинающим? Я, когда начинал разбираться с данной тематикой (причем придя в нее из Delphi), лопатил горы разрозненной информации по всем этим страшным аббревиатурам, выписанным в списочек из вакансий по Java. 

Если бы у меня тогда был некий приоритетный планчик, было бы легче.

Comment: > типа придут на форум, зададут вопрос, прочитают 5-10 книг, которые им посоветовали, и станут профессионалами

Речь не о том чтобы стать профессионалом за 24 часа. Проблема в том, чтобы правильно сориентироваться в обильном потоке информации. Чтобы с чего то начать.

Comment: так в том то и дело, что бы тоже думал, что если осилю что-то из книг типа "идеальный код", то сразу стану все понимать, на практике книгу закидываешь на 10 стр, потому что не понимаешь о чем она. Обычно планы которые рекомендуют - это план, который был бы хорош ТОЛЬКО АВТОРУ ЭТОГО ПЛАНА, когда он начинал программировать, и это не означает, что он подойдет тебе. Например я бы рекомендовал, html, css, аплеты и потом сервлет - остальное, фреймворки и технологии уже крутятся вокруг основ. Вот из списка выше п.9 - почему спринг, почему не обобщенный DI(IoC)?

Comment: Ну так на то он и хэшкод, чтобы все могли высказать свои мысли, а ТС  на их основе сам сделал выводы. Хотя бы путем усреднения ответов. Планчик-то, конечно, у каждого свой, но общие моменты все равно найдутся, а по ходу дела и самому можно определиться, куда копать. Хуже не знать ВООБЩЕ с какой стороны подступиться.